# Filter a tensor on the basis of a python list in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor `a` of type `tf.int64`. I want to filter out this tensor on the basis of a given python list.
For example -

```py
l = [1,2,3]
a = tf.constant([1,2,3,4], dtype=tf.int64)
```

Need a tensor with values `1,2,3` except `4`. That is filtering out `a` on the basis of `l`. How can I do this in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `tf.sets.set_intersection`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    l = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.int64)
    a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=tf.int64)
    # tf.sets.intersection in more recent versions
    b = tf.sets.set_intersection(tf.expand_dims(a, 0), tf.expand_dims(l, 0))
    b = tf.squeeze(tf.sparse.to_dense(b), 0)
    print(sess.run(b))
    # [1 2 3]
```

But this probably does not do what you want in many cases. If there are duplicate elements it will discard them, and it will sort the output too. More generally, you can just do this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    l = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.int64)
    a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=tf.int64)
    m = tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(a, 1), l), axis=1)
    b = tf.boolean_mask(a, m)
    print(sess.run(b))
    # [1 2 3]
```

It is a quadratic comparison, but I don't think there is anything better like [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) in TensorFlow.

Comment: If suppose `a` (tensor which is to be filtered) is 3D tensor instead of 1D then what will be the changes to be done.

Comment: @AbhilashAwasthi Yes, probably, maybe if you can give an example of how exactly you mean so (either here or in a new question) it would be easier to tell.

Comment: In case of other than 1D tensor, the second answer can be modified like this `m = tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(a, -1), l), axis=-1)`